# Angular ignores the iframe element

Tags: angular, iframe

I've found Angular 15 to be ignoring the iframe element. I've found the following existing example on stackblitz that is not working either. In both cases I've found the iframe element to be simply missing from the dom.

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-iframe-src?file=src/app/app.component.html

Is this a bug in Angular? Or both me and the example are missing something?

Answer (score 0):

The pages you are trying to frame forbid being framed and throw a "Refused to display document because display forbidden by X-Frame-Options." error in Chrome.

If they're your pages, then remove the frame limiter. Otherwise, respect the page's author's wishes and DON'T FRAME THEM.

[Working StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-with-iframe?file=src%2Fapp%2Fiframe%2Fiframe.component.ts)

[Reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6666423/overcoming-display-forbidden-by-x-frame-options#answer-7469997)